# List instance does not recognized in method context in C#

Tags: c#, list, compiler-errors, ienumerable

I am trying to understand why compiler throws an error when I try to use "List" specific method "Add" in this context. The error explanation states that it is because of the field definition. (IEnumerable does not include "Add" method) However, I newed it in inner context. I will be grateful for a reasonable explanation.

Note: I know that is because IEnumerable is an interface and I can use IList instead. However, what I could not understand is that compiler should extract the type in inner context but its not.

```
class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> exampleList;
    public static void Main()
    {
        exampleList = new List<string>();
        exampleList.Add("ex"); // ==> Compiler Error Here.
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is specific and explains the problem. `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an `Add` method. Did you mean to declare the `exampleList` as a `List<string>` instead?

Comment: That's what encapsulation in OOP is all about.

Comment: What I did not understand is why compiler does not extract the type in inner context, but now I realized thats because newing operation is in runtime, so compiler throws an error, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `exampleList` is defined as an `IEnumerable<string>`, so its *compile-time* type is an `IEnumerable<string>`. Therefore, when the compiler is compiling the code, it can only know that it is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Two main fixes exist:

1) Declare exampleList as an IList

```
private static IList<string> exampleList;
```

2) Use a temporary variable to set the list contents.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("ex");
    exampleList = list;
}
```

Just to briefly explain why the compiler can only know that it is an IEnumerable, consider the following code:

```
IEnumerable<string> exampleList;

if (TodayIsAWednesday()) 
{
    exampleList = new List<string>();
}
else 
{
    exampleList = new string[0];
}

// How can the compiler know that exampleList is a List<string>? 
// It can't!
exampleList.Add("ex");
```

Comment: Upvoted, I was just thinking for adding an answer with something similar to the latter snippet.

Comment: Thanks, but what I could not understand is that compiler should extract the type in inner context but its not. I already solved it by using IList instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: @skynyrd simply put: That's not how it works. If your variable is defined for a specific type it can only use methods of that specific type.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below, will solve the problem.

```
private static List<string> exampleList;
```

or change your code in static Main as below

```
var newCollection = exampleList.ToList();
newCollection.Add("ex"); //is your new collection with the item added
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see,"I" meant it is a Interface.It can accept all kind of Enumerable,but have not Add's Method.
You can see:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx